# After removing spinners for input type number why mozila allows user to enter alphabet values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to stop to enter alphabets in input type number in Mozilla after removing spinners using CSS

```
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Comment: It's because by setting `-moz-appearance:textfield;` you've effectively turned the input in to a `type="text"`. If you want users to only be allowed to enter numbers without the spinners you'll need to use a standard `text` input, and restrict the characters with JS, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/469362/519413 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/995193/519413

Comment: On a side note, firefox allows entering non-numeric characters into `input type="number"` anyway